# How to design this UI in Android?

Tags: android, uiview

[image: RequiredUi]

Actually, I don't have any `png` for this but I need to design like this image in Android. I am trying to draw using canvas but unable to create as per the same requirement. So please suggest me how I can able to draw it in Android. I don't know graphics design.

Comment: Add code which you tried

Comment: What does the arrow do? It looks like a draggable/swipable vertical bar - how should the user interact with it?

Comment: All have clickable property

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom view.

Create [Path Objects](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) and use [drawPath()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPath(android.graphics.Path,%20android.graphics.Paint)) inside your custom View.